# Transparent UITableView on top of several UIViewController and OpenGLView (Cocos2D)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, uicolor

Here is my code  :

```
// View Controller with navigation bar
InAppPurchaseViewController *purchaseViewController = [[InAppPurchaseViewController alloc] init];
purchaseViewController.title = @"Magasin";
purchaseViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissViewController:)] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:purchaseViewController] autorelease];

// Add `purchaseViewcontroller` TO container AND container ON openGLView
UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[container setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];
[container setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[container presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The `UITableView` is in purchaseViewController.

I was thinking of using `[UIColor clearColor]`, BUT whatever I use it on I get a BLACK background on my `UITableView`. The cells get unselectable and unslidable (apart from the elements that are into the cells)

EDIT : The appdelegate

Here is the .h

```
@class AudioEngine;
@class RootViewController;
@class Score;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate>

@property int CurrentPackage;
@property int CurrentScore;
@property int CurrentHighScore;
@property BOOL SoundShouldPlay;
@property BOOL PauseScreenUp;
@property(nonatomic, retain) AudioEngine *CustomAudioEngine;
@property(nonatomic, retain) GameCenterManager *CustomGameCenterManager;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) RootViewController *ViewController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* CurrentLeaderBoard;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *TenLastScoresArray;

+(AppDelegate *)get;
-(void)connectToGameCenter;
-(void)addScoreToLastScore:(Score*)score;
```

And the method did finish launching

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();
    self.CurrentLeaderBoard = kLeaderboardID;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[InAppPurchaseSingleton sharedHelper]];
    [AudioEngine preloadBackgroundMusic];
    [AudioEngine playBackgroundMusic:3];
    self.SoundShouldPlay = YES;
    [SceneManager goSplash];
}
```

Comment: you having the tableview object set it clear color property

Comment: Try: 1- Set BG to `[UIColor clearColor]` for **`UITableView` & `UITableViewCell`**. 2- Set `Opaque` to `NO` for **`UITableView` & `UITableViewCell`**.

Comment: Have you tried and see what happens if you don't do: `[container setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];`? Just to clear out if it is some kind of glitch between UITableView and Cocos2D...

Comment: Yes if i don't set the openGLView the modal UIViewController just doesn't show up. Basically nothing happens =/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of presenting the view controller on `container`:

```
UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
...
[container presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

what should work is presenting it on the root view controller that the cocos2D template created for you. It is normally accessible through the app delegate:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = (UIViewController*)[(YOURAPPDELEGATE*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
[rootViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`viewController` is an ivar that the cocos2D default template add to the application delegate class. It is normally private, so you will need to define an accessor:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) RootViewController *viewController; //-- .h file

@synthesize viewController; //-- .m file
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Based on what I have in my app delegate, I think you could try and instantiate the RootViewController like this:

```
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT
ViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
ViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[ViewController setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];
    ...
```

Comment: What is "viewController" in the first line ?

Comment: So i quickly tried but it seems that it's not enough. For now my application is openGLview based (i use coco2d scene and layer and i pop viewControllers on top of it). The problem is that i don't want to do the opposite...  With this rootViewController method nothing happen when i press the "PurchaseButton" and i don't know why. There is no error...

Comment: would you kindly post your app delegate interface definition and the body of your `appDidFinishLoading`? I use that method and it works, so there should be something wrong with your `viewController` member. Have you checked it is not nil when you present the other view controller?

Comment: which version of Cocos2D are you using?

Comment: I use V1.0.0 why do you ask ?

Comment: the project created by my cocos2D template is different from yours... your app delegate does not seem to use `RootViewController`, mine (v. 0.99.5) does... so just thinking of checking this...

Comment: This is the first time i use cocos2d, so i may be using it wrong. At first i was doin the configuration manualy and i had a viewController to manage the orientation of the device. I got ride of it and used the method CC_DIRECTOR_INIT() which kind of do every basic config by itself.